# Bash script to open a terminal and cd to a variable directory

Tags: linux, bash, gnome-terminal

I want to write a bash script that opens a gnome-terminal in a directory in `~/Documents/` according to the argument passed to it (e.g. `./open.sh notes` opens the terminal in `~/Documents/notes/`)

How would I go about that? I know `gnome-terminal --working-directory=[directory]` does something similar, but it doesn't accept strings so I don't know if it can be used in this case.

Comment: If it doesn't accept strings then what *does* it accept? Lollipops?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this;

```
#!/bin/bash
workDir="/home/user/Documents/$1"
if [ ! -d "$workDir" ]; then
    echo "directory not found, check your path"
else
    gnome-terminal --working-directory="$workDir"
fi
```

Example;

```
./open.sh notes
```

this open a new terminal in ~/Documents/notes

Comment: You *need* to quote the parameter expansion in case the given directory contains characters that produce pathname expansion or word-splitting. I have fixed it twice, and you've reverted the change each time.

Answer (score 0):

Your script, or function, could simply be:

```
open() {
    gnome-terminal --working-directory="Documents/$1"
}
```

It looks like the working directory can be specified relative to the user's home directory.

Use it like `open notes` to open a new terminal in `~/Documents/notes`.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean exactly - could you explain?

Comment: @Inian `basename` and `dirname` split a path into two parts; you can't use them to reconstruct an absolute path from a relative path.

Comment: I guess I failed to convey my actual point again :) How will this logic work for a folder say `/home/foobar/Downloads/My_movies`? The response for this will make my query clear. Thanks!

Comment: @Inian it won't work at all but I'm not sure how it could be changed to work for that case without breaking it for the case that the OP has specified.